# User Access to SVN Context Menu

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Currently we are working in Apache SVN and we use TortoiseSVN as client. The Project team includes Manager(s), Lead(s), BA(s), Dev(s). My requirement is to restrict Dev(s) only to checkout, Update, Commit and other basic commands except Merge, Branch/Tag, Switch. Is that possible to grant access to certain menu items in SVN based upon the user credentials ? Is there any workaround is there ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [it's possible](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-admins-disablemenus.html), but this is, in common, **The Bad Way (tm)** (stupid, not bullet-proof).

Better choice to block *some operations* for *some users* is using hooks with all-needed-logic in it